# How to pass parameters in correct way from view to controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, controller, erb

I've some time working with Rails but I have a problem and  don't know how to solve.

There is a model X and a model YW and between them a joint model

I need to pass from view to controller as part of the parameters the X the x_yw_attributes but I don't know how stablish the correct way of the attribute name in html.

The idea will be this:

```
"x" => {
"name"=>"Name 1", "description"=>"Descripción 1", "status"=>"true",
"x_yw_attributes" =>[
            {"yw_id"=>"15", "range"=>"[1,2,3,5]", "payment" => "[2,3,4,5,6,7]"},  
            {"yw_id"=>"17", "range"=>"[1000,2000,3000,5000]", "payment" => "[20,30,40,50,60,70]"},
            {"yw_id"=>"19", "range"=>"[10000,20000,30000,50000]", "payment" => "[200,300,400,500,600,700]"}
           ], 
"categories_ids"=>["", "2", "", "5", "5"]
}
```

I know how to do it with the categories for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="x[category_ids][]" value="2" checked="checked">
<label for="category_2">Category 2</label>
```

So let me know how should I write the name attribute or I you need more info.
Thaks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the document with more detail [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
And from your question I can't tell where do you want to store the information, in YW or the joint table?
If you want to store data in YW, you can set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :yw` first, and then pass `yw_attributes` to controller. 
The strong parameters would be something like:

```rb
def x_params
  params.requires(:x).permit(:name, :description, :status, yw_attributes: [:id, :range, :payment, :_destroy])
end
```

The code you wrote looks like to store information in the join_table. If that's you want to do, add :id into x_yw_attributes to indicate that you want update rather than create them.

You can also check [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) by Ryan B. which he combines some javascript code to make the life easier